# PowerBI ExportReport Stream format

Tags: .net-core, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am using PowerBI online with pro license.

Using PowerBIClient object in .Net core 2.1 I am able to ExportReport function which is returning me Stream.

I want to convert this into an image ( any format) so I can use it further. How do I get this done? Am I thinking correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it doesn't work this way. [ExportReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exportreport) returns you the .pbix file, i.e. the report itself, which can be opened in Power BI Desktop. There is no easy way to convert this to an image pragmatically.

You can save this stream to a .pbix file and try to open it in Power BI Desktop. If the data is imported, or in case you have access to the data source, you will be able to visualize the report and export it to PDF, but this is manual operation. Also, you can export the report from the service directly (to [PowerPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-powerpoint) and [PDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-pdf)).

You can try to automate Power BI Desktop (e.g. using [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver)), but I wouldn't go this way for a production system.

There are also some 3rd party tools that eventually can help you (e.g. [this one](https://www.powerbitiles.com/?app=PBIRobots)).

You can [embed Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers) in a desktop application and try some [screen capturing magic](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/12/01/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-in-net-core/), but this isn't nice and easy solution either.

You can suggest an idea or vote for existing one in [Power BI Ideas](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi), e.g. [Export to PDF via Power BI Embedded API](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/35066698-export-to-pdf-via-power-bi-embedded-api).

UPDATE 2020: There is Export to File API now - [Export report to PDF, PPTX and PNG files using Power BI REST API (Preview)](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-report-to-pdf-pptx-and-png-files-using-power-bi-rest-api/), [Reports - Export To File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofile), [Reports - Export To File In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofileingroup).